# How do I change the color of the MFMessageComposeViewController elements?

Tags: ios, ios7, mfmessagecomposeviewcontroller

I set up and open my MFMessageComposeViewController with the following:

```
- (void)openSMSViewWithRecipientsArray:(NSArray *)recipients {
    MFMessageComposeViewController *messageVC = [MFMessageComposeViewController new];

    if([MFMessageComposeViewController canSendText]){
        messageVC.body = @"";
        [[messageVC navigationBar] setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
        messageVC.recipients = recipients;
        messageVC.messageComposeDelegate = self;
        [self presentViewController:messageVC animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
}
```

But the screen looks like this:

[image]

So how do I change either the purple background where the numbers are, or change the number colors along with the plus sign color?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I couldn't change only the purple background where the numbers were, so I had to change the whole nav bar color so it would apply to the background of the numbers:

```
- (void)setNavBarColor:(UIColor *)navBarColor titleColor:(UIColor *)titleColor {
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor:navBarColor];
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                                          [UIFont fontWithName:@"Futura-Medium" size:17.0f],
                                                          UITextAttributeFont,
                                                          titleColor,
                                                          UITextAttributeTextColor,
                                                          nil]];
}
```

Comment: where should I call the method - (void)setNavBarColor:(UIColor *)navBarColor titleColor:(UIColor *)titleColor

Comment: @user2955351, Before you initialise `MFMessageComposeViewController`.