# Changing MFMessageComposeViewController recipients text color

Tags: ios, ios7, uinavigationbar, mfmessagecomposeviewcontroller

When sending an SMS in `iOS7` using `MFMessageComposeViewController`, some of the `UINavigationBar` and SMS recipients bar conforms to the `[UINavigationBar appearance]`; however, some is also missing. First, the text of the Cancel button is the default blue color instead of my desired white. I have managed to fix this with

```
[[messageController navigationBar] setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
```

However, the text of the recipients and the add(+) button is also using default Colors (green and blue). The background color is inherited from UINavigationBar, but not the text Colors. Are there any ways of changing these text Colors ?

Comment: Take a look http://stackoverflow.com/q/19410135/1597744 , http://stackoverflow.com/q/19017305/1597744

Comment: Oh, my Google skills are poor today ... However, I did not find any solutions there (actually changing the text). Impossible?

Comment: @Jom could you find a solution for the problem ?

Comment: No, still looking for a solution ...